# Redirect HTTP REQUEST FROM SPRING TO ANGULAR(10) WITH VALUES

Tags: angular, spring-boot, rest, http, spring-mvc

I have my server backend that is called from a client X(clickable link) with HTTP GET REQUEST this client send me values as RequestHeader, my need is to get these values (headers) and send it to My frontend (ANGULAR) and the most important thing is to get those values and continue my workflow.

the image below explain my workflow

[image]

this is my java code(spring controller)

```
private static final String NG_REDIRECT_URL= "http://localhost:4200";


@GetMapping(value = "/server-core")
    public RedirectView requestHandler(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
            @RequestHeader(value = "user_id", required = true) String userId,
            @RequestHeader(value = "login", required = true) String login) throws IOException {
        return new RedirectView(NG_REDIRECT_URL, true);
    }
```

Comment: If you need to sent anything with a redirect, you’ll have to use query params in the url..

Comment: something like this http://localhost:4200/list?login=login_value&user_id=user_value   ???? if my provided example is correct how to intercept thoses params from angular app. THANK U

Comment: You can read those values from the ActivatedRoute snapshot.. https://reactgo.com/angular-get-query-params/

Comment: thank u for ur response, but I try the ActivatedRoute inside the onInit method of app.component.ts (root component) and I get undefined value

Comment: Well you’re navigating to /list so I guess there is a list component? That is where you’ll have access to it..

Comment: Sorry I just modified my URL because I can't access to /list until I'm not logged so I need to get values in app.component.ts then call login method to generate token and redirect to list.

Comment: im also working on same , but mines is going in loop after redirection any solutions please

Answer (score 1):

You need add the values as query parameters in the url of the angular and you need to get those parameters in **app.component.ts** with the help of following and do your operations with the values

```
ngOnInit() {
     const url = window.location.href;
     if (url.includes('?')) {
        const httpParams = new HttpParams({ fromString: url.split('?')[1] });
        const token = httpParams.get("token");
        //Here you will have you operations and you navigation with the parameters
        //this.router.navigate(['/home']);
     } else {
        //Here you will have your actual redirection
     }
}
```

And avoid using empty path redirection in **routing module (ex. app.routing-module.ts)**.Try manual navigation to the page in **app.component.ts**

I think this will help you...